Is a sequential binomial sample a multinomial sample?
Say I have N particles and I remove a fraction $f_1$ of these obtaining $k_1$ particles as
$$ k_1 \sim \text{Binomial}(N,f_1) $$
and from these selected $k_1$ I have another Binomial draw of $k_2$ from a fraction $f_2$
$$ k_2 \sim \text{Binomial}(k_1,f_2)  . $$
The particles remaining at each selections are $n_1 = k_1-k_2$ and $n_2=k_2$, which represents fractions of the original total $\phi_1 = f_1 (1-f_2)$ and $\phi_2 = f_1 f_2$.
Intuitively it seems natural to assume that the pair $(n_1,n_2)$ is equivalent to a multinomial. Meaning
$$ \left( n_1,n_2,N-(n_1+n_2) \right) \sim \text{Multinomial}(N,(\phi_1,\phi_2, 1-(\phi_1+\phi_2)) $$
But I have been struggling to prove it, does anyone here have done this or know a reference?  Thanks

An easy way to see this is that each particle has a probability $f_1f_2$ of being counted among the $k_2$, a probability $f_1(1-f_2)$ of of being counted among the $k_1$ but not the $k_2$, and a probability $1-f_1$ of being counted among neither, and that this is independent of how all the other particles are counted.  So the number of particles in each of these three sets has a multinomial distribution.

There's an immediate proof:

each particle can be in three states: unselected, pass the first check, pass both checks.

the probability of each state is easily computed.

the probability of the particles being in the states are independent

the total counts of independent variales is a multinomial. (NB: in a full proof, we would need to enumerate the cases here).



After working the algebra a couple more times I realize it was just a mistake and my intuition was right.
The first step draws $k_1 \sim \text{Binomial}(N, f_1)$, with:
$$
P(k_1|N) = \binom{N}{k_1} f_1^{k_1} (1 - f_1)^{N - k_1}.
$$
The second step draws $k_2 \sim \text{Binomial}(k_1, f_2)$, independently of $N$ with:
$$
P(k_2 |k_1) = \binom{k_1}{n_2} f_2^{n_2} (1 - f_2)^{k_1 - n_2}.
$$
Thus the joint is
$$
P((k_1,k_2)|N) = P(k_1|N) \ P(k_2|k_1) = \binom{N}{k_1} f_1^{k_1} (1 - f_1)^{N - k_1}   \  \binom{k_1}{k_2} f_2^{k_2} (1 - f_2)^{k_1 - k_2}.
$$
Replace $k_1 = n_1 + n_2$ and $k_2=n_2$ :
$$
P(n_1, n_2|N) = \frac{N!}{(n_1 + n_2)! (N - n_1 - n_2)!} f_1^{n_1 + n_2} (1 - f_1)^{N - (n_1 + n_2)} \ \frac{(n_1 + n_2)!}{n_2! n_1!} f_2^{n_2} (1 - f_2)^{n_1}.
$$
Simplify and factorize:
$$
P(n_1, n_2|N) = \frac{N!}{(n_1 + n_2)! (N - n_1 - n_2)!} \frac{(n_1 + n_2)!}{n_2! n_1!} 
(f_1 (1 - f_2))^{n_1} \cdot (f_1 f_2)^{n_2} \cdot (1 - f_1)^{N - (n_1 + n_2)}.
$$
Recognizing the effective probabilities:
$$
\phi_1 = f_1 (1 - f_2), \quad \phi_2 = f_1 f_2, \quad \phi_3 = 1 - (\phi_1 + \phi_2),
$$
we rewrite the probability as:
$$
P(n_1, n_2, N - (n_1 + n_2)) = \frac{N!}{n_1! n_2! (N - (n_1 + n_2))!} \phi_1^{n_1} \phi_2^{n_2} \phi_3^{N - (n_1 + n_2)}.
$$
This matches the form of the multinomial distribution:
$$
(n_1, n_2, N-(n_1+n_2)) \sim \text{Multinomial}(N, (\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3)).
$$
